# Using msvcrt.getch() in Eclipse / PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev, msvcrt

I wanted to use `msvcrt.getch()` in Eclipse with PyDev to read a signe char but I found out that it just don't work (but It works in the Windows console).

Any idea what to do ?

Comment: That's not really possible. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303939/110451

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `sys.stdin.read` when run in PyDev? like `sys.stdin.read(1)` read 1 line from input...For use in Windows console and in PyDev make same selection based on os and run variants(using `sys.stdin.isatty`). For example next code read timelimited user input. But when run in Windows console if program's standard input is piped in with another program's standard output, then `sys.stdin.isatty` returns `False` and input read with `sys.stdin.read`, not `msvcrt.getch`:

```
import sys, time
import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    import msvcrt
else:
    from select import select

def input_with_timeout_sane(prompt, timeout, default):
    """Read an input from the user or timeout"""
    print prompt,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if rlist:
        s = sys.stdin.readline().replace('\n','')
    else:
        s = default
        print s
    return s
def input_with_timeout_windows(prompt, timeout, default): 
    start_time = time.time()
    print prompt,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    input = ''
    read_f=msvcrt.getche
    input_check=msvcrt.kbhit
    if not sys.stdin.isatty( ):
        read_f=lambda:sys.stdin.read(1)
        input_check=lambda:True
    while True:
        if input_check():
            chr_or_str = read_f()
            try:
                if ord(chr_or_str) == 13: # enter_key
                    break
                elif ord(chr_or_str) >= 32: #space_char
                    input += chr_or_str
            except:
                input=chr_or_str
                break #read line,not char...        
        if len(input) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            break
    if len(input) > 0:
        return input
    else:
        return default

def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout, default=''):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        return input_with_timeout_windows(prompt, timeout, default)
    else:
        return input_with_timeout_sane(prompt, timeout, default)

print "\nAnswer is:"+input_with_timeout("test?",10,"no input entered")
```