# No value and no error from event handler

Tags: python

Whenever I press the ESC key (anywhere on my desktop), I would like to print a message.

This is what I have so far:

```
from msvcrt import getch
while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 27:
        print('Key pressed.')
```

When I run this code and hit ESC, I get nothing - not even an error. Why?

`print(key)` keeps giving me 255 repeatedly, even if I press nothing.

Comment: What module is this?

Comment: i managed to make this code work on a windows with python and ironpython, inside the REPL, as Mothrakk said

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine if you open the script through the console (double click on the file, not with IDLE).

You want a low-level keyboard hook. This simply listens to the keypresses made to the console, not anywhere else.

Comment: Yeah this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076853/using-msvcrt-getch-in-eclipse-pydev) discussion talks about how it doesn't work unless you use the console or another method.