# Single character input in Pydev / Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I want to capture a single user keypress without "enter", and see afterward whether it was  'r' or 'b' etc, but specifically in Eclipse with PyDev (Windows 7: 64bit, Python 3.6.1). Many nice alternatives are mentioned in [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) of course. The mrvcrt seems to work in cmd.exe but not in PyDev:

```py
import msvcrt
mych = msvcrt.getwch()
print('You pressed: ' + mych)
```

Why not? I see @MatthieuRiegler already asked this at [Using msvcrt.getch() in Eclipse / PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076853/using-msvcrt-getch-in-eclipse-pydev) ... but I am open to anything that works, not necessarily mrvcrt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `PyDev/Eclipse` doesn't give you a real terminal (your program is launched without a 'real' console and it just redirects the outputs).

So, the alternative is checking whether you're in this scenario with:

```
import sys
is_in_terminal = sys.stdin.isatty()

if not is_in_terminal:
    entered = input()  # input() on Py3, on Py2 it'd be raw_input()
else:
    import msvcrt
    entered = msvcrt.getwch()
```

The only thing is that if it's not in a terminal, the contents are only available to the program on a new line (so, it's not really possible to get that output without him pressing enter).

Note that having a 'real' terminal could be possible, although it'd require some terminal emulation inside Eclipse -- such as https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tcf-terminals -- and then PyDev could launch a program in such a terminal instead of using the console view... (but this is just in the ideas world, there's not due date for that, so, unfortunately, it's not currently possible to grab a single char without an enter inside PyDev/Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks that explains things! Much appreciated